# Find dropdown all values selected in jquery

Tags: jquery

Anybody knows how to see check the dropdown all values is selected using jquery.

I have dropdown by default the first values is select all, need to find the select all is selected or not in jquery.

Any help please?. I have an idea how to find the selected value but struggling to find how to check the all value is selected.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please Enter your Code

Answer (score 0):

If you have an idea how to find the selected value, then count selected values and your total values in dropdown. If selcted count and total count are equal then all are selected otherwise few are selected.

Or please provide your demp code to get exact solution.